# Decision problems involving finite automata

Tags: finite-automata, decision-problem

A finite automaton (FA), A, may accept or reject its own encoding, {A}.  A machine, M, can be written that accepts {A} iff A rejects {A}.  Turing gave a famous proof that M is not an FA.  The proof relies on a contradiction that occurs when one assumes M is an FA and then runs M on its own encoding.  However, it may still be possible that M is an FA that correctly decides a large class of inputs other than {M}.

I’d like to know what’s in that class, so I’m interested in finding prior work done on this topic.  Can anyone point my towards the relevant literature?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466770/is-there-a-good-enough-solution-for-the-halting-problem.

Comment: The answer depends on $M$, of course. A more interesting question could be the following. Is there a linear countable hierarchy of $M$ that can accept increasingly more such $A$ and all of them can accept all such $A$?